# PL/SQL displaying a database table with HTML only

Tags: android, html, sql, plsql

Without using PHP, is there a way to grab data from a database table and transfer it into an html table? Here is my initial code, Please let me know if there are any more information I can provide, I am still new to stack overflow.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE package PCSPRO.SDRP15_Status_Report as

PROCEDURE ALFRED_proc1;


END SDRP15_STATUS_REPORT;
/ 
show errors;


----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pcspro.SDRP15_STATUS_REPORT AS

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

procedure alfred_proc1

is

begin 


HTP.P('

<HTML>
<BODY>
<table bgcolor="White"> Status Report
<b><font size="4" color=black>Submission Log</font></b>
<table bgcolor="black" width=1020 align="center" border="0"  cellspacing="1" class="sortable"><THEAD><tr bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<th width=30 align=left><font size="2">DEL</font></th>
<th width=50 align=left><font size="2">EDT</font></th>

<th width=30 align=left><font size="2">Phase</font></th>
<th width=50 align=left><font size="2">State</font></th>
<th width=414 align=left><font size="2">CHG</font></th>
<th width=30 align=left><font size="2">Changes</font></th>
<th width=180 align=left><font size="2">Completed</font></th>
</table>

</BODY>
</HTML>

');

end alfred_proc1;
```

and  my table is as follows:

```
SDRP15 table
   | phase |      |state|     |chg|
   ---------      -------     -----
       A          Maryland      Y
       V          New York      N
       A          Florida       N
```

Comment: Are you running Oracle on Android?

Comment: I am using MySQL as a compiler while using Toad for oracle to code for PLSQL and html/javascript

Comment: @jarlh On the plus side, it's more powerful than SQLite. On the minus side, this phone weighs a ton and a half and Oracle keep chasing me for a licence fee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible, somthing along the lines of the below should work if you just want to create a table with values. So basicly craete a cursor at the top to retrieve the values from the database, then loop through the return and output the values.

---

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pcspro.SDRP15_STATUS_REPORT AS

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

procedure alfred_proc1

is

cursor c_values is 
select phase, state, chg 
from   *yourtable*
where  *yourconditions*;

begin 


HTP.P('

<HTML>
<BODY>
<table bgcolor="White"> Status Report
<b><font size="4" color=black>Submission Log</font></b>
<table bgcolor="black" width=1020 align="center" border="0"  cellspacing="1" class="sortable"><THEAD><tr bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<th width=30 align=left><font size="2">DEL</font></th>
<th width=50 align=left><font size="2">EDT</font></th>

<th width=30 align=left><font size="2">Phase</font></th>
<th width=50 align=left><font size="2">State</font></th>
<th width=414 align=left><font size="2">CHG</font></th>
<th width=30 align=left><font size="2">Changes</font></th>
<th width=180 align=left><font size="2">Completed</font></th> ');

for v_values in c_values loop 
   htp.p('<tr><td width=30 align=left></td>');
   htp.p('<td width=50 align=left></td>');
   htp.p('<td width=30 align=left>' || c_values.phase || '</td>');
   htp.p('<td width=50 align=left>' || c_values.state || '</td>');
   htp.p('<td width=414 align=left>' || c_values.change || '</td>');
   htp.p('<td width=30 align=left></td>');
   htp.p('<td width=180 align=left></td></tr>');

end loop;

htp.p('</table>    
</BODY>
</HTML>');

end alfred_proc1;
```